# Becoming Owner onsite

Tags: phpmyadmin

I bought a website yesterday. I have been given the SQL file, and I can see the domain is in my name.

The previous owner has now blocked me from talking to them. 
before sale I did request after purchase support and this was confirmed. (this isn't going to happen i take it)

I am not trained in SQL, web systems, phpVMS and or others.

The site is currently online but no one can join 
1, I'm not a member on the site yet.
2, The reCaptcha has a error ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key.

I have had a look at phpMyAdmin and I have added myself, very proud moment. I can see myself on the website. But when I go to log into the site it states invalid login, please check your password and username.

I must be missing something here and was wondering if you might be able to assist me.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need pay someone to fix the things to you. The reCaptcha error is because it requires an API key, and the old API key is limited only to the old domain (supposing that you changed it). You must create a new api key and replace it whereever is it.

Comment: Also your login problem should be about password hashing. IF the site was coded properly, (you didn't told if it's hand coded, or if it's over a platform like Wordpress), the passwords are not stored in plain text on database, but hashed (a kind of irreversible encryption)

Comment: Hello Elias, Thank you for your reply. I can say it is with the same domain. Ill have a look at creating a new API.

Comment: Investigating, if I'm right, the phpVMS that you told is an virtual airlines platform write in PHP using Laravel framework. Passwords in Laravel are hashed as I told, so that's the reason you cant make things work.

Comment: Try setting you password column on PhpMyAdmin to `$2y$10$6wh9FOYY2UqhldK2zB.csu.Q/vndBhmDfPADfzty.8s7bnws0SmpW` this is a hash for `secret` password. Then try to login with you user and `secret` as password

Comment: I can help you later, going to lunch now. Please tell me if the password worked, then later I reply you.

Comment: Yes phpVMS is for virtual airline platform.

Comment: I have tried the password give $2y$10$6wh9FOYY2UqhldK2zB.csu.Q/vndBhmDfPADfzty.8s7bnws0SmpW   but it says its too long only 32 charters needed

Comment: So you have the old version of phpvms. When I come back I look at source code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Change the user password manually:

The password on phpVMS (old version, not Laravel based one) uses a salted md5 hashing (old technologies, not so safe as current bcrypt).

To change the password, you will need to change two fields on the user table: `salt` and `password`:

```
>>> $salt = md5(date('His'));
=> "b18991bc99fdb46e1d40d415b77e8323" // Use this value on `salt` column
>>> $password = md5('secret' . $salt)
=> "7df97d8ba1f5d10f94611ee6ce387827" // Use this value on `password` column
```

Change this, you should have access to your account using `secret` as password.

## Making recaptcha work

The recaptcha settings are under `core/app.config.php`, search for `RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY` and `RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY`, or under `core/local.config.php` (not sure if youn need to change on both files.

You need to create an API public and private key pair on [Recaptcha page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) following all given steps and replace the values you received for api public and private keys.

## Notice

The version of phpVMS on your site is old, no more updated by project owner. It might contain several security issues, pay attention to it.

Comment: Hi, I have been able to log into the site now. Thank you

Comment: Not sure, but I think that the recaptcha configuration may be done in the admin panel too.

Comment: I cant seem to find the core/app.config.php

Comment: HI Elias, sorry to bother you again. I was wondering if you could just let me know how I could change my password. for my php admin. I haven't done it yet since i brought the website.